# Acceso a controles de un formulario MDIcontainer desde sus formularios hijos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando un fomulario MDIcontainer con un panel que lo usaré como barra de estado en la parte de abajo para mostrar labels y un progressbar con información de algún proceso que se realize dentro los formularios hijos, el problema que tengo es que no puedo mostrar u ocultar un label que se encuentra en esa barra de estado del formulario MDIcontainer ¿Hay alguna manera de tener acceso a los controles del Formulario MDIcontainer desde sus hijos?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: y si usas eventos? los controles hijos declaran eventos a los que el control padre se puede suscribir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu formulario que funciona como MDI container declara los controles que quieres exponer como public, aquí te pongo el ejemplo del control ToolStripStatusLabel

```
    public ToolStripStatusLabel ToolStripStatusLabel
    {
        get { return tsslNombreUsuario; }
    }
```

Ahora en el formulario que va a ser el hijo (MDI Child) accedes a la propiedad MdiParent para extraer el padre y como ya tienes como public el control ToolStripStatusLabel puedes acceder a él:

```
            FormMdiParent mdiParent = (FormMdiParent)this.MdiParent; //FormMdiParent es el tipo de clase de tu formulario MDIParent
            mdiParent.ToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Asignando valor a ToolStrip en Mdi Parent desde Mdi child";
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alfredo, me funcionó. Saludos