# Acceder a controles de un formulario activo

Tags: c#

Gente,
Esta es mi primer pregunta, siempre he encontrado mis respuestas buscando pero aquí tengo una que no logro resolver.

Tengo un formulario que se carga dentro de un `MDI` padre (Creado en C#). Este formulario tiene un dentro un `SplitContainer`, dentro del Primer panel cargo un control que contiene un `DataGridView`. Cuando el usuario da doble click sobre una fila recupero el valor de una celda para realizar una búsqueda en una BD y los valores que me regresa necesito pasarlos al segundo panel, al cual debo agregarle un control (en el segundo panel) que contiene 3 `TextBox` donde depositaré los resultados de la consulta antes realizada.

La verdad es que no tengo idea de como hacer para que el primer control cargado en el `panel1` pueda cargar el control en el `panel2` y pasarle los valores recuperados.

¿Me expliqué correctamente?

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su ayuda. 
Saludos.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201403/acceso-a-controles-de-un-formulario-mdicontainer-desde-sus-formularios-hijos/201430#201430

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Acceso a controles de un formulario MDIcontainer desde sus formularios hijos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201403/acceso-a-controles-de-un-formulario-mdicontainer-desde-sus-formularios-hijos)

Comment: Gracias por su pronta respuesta, compañeros.

Intenté aplicar la solución, pero dado que el control en el panel1 esta contenido dentro de este mismo al insertar este código me manda error:
``````C#
FormMdiParent mdiParent = (FormMdiParent)this.MdiParent; //FormMdiParent es el tipo de clase de tu formulario MDIParent
            mdiParent.ToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Asignando valor a ToolStrip en Mdi Parent desde Mdi child";
``````
Resulta que el MDIParent de mi control es el SplitGroupControl y me decuelve un error diciendo que no puede convertir a un form

Answer (score 1):

Gente, ya lo resolví...

Para poder acceder a las propiedades del control en el primer panel, desde el control del segundo panel, utilicé este código:

```
((SplitContainerControl)((SplitGroupPanel)(this.Parent)).Parent).Panel2.Controls.Add(xfrmDatosExp.Instance);
```